# How can I get value from object in sub-collection with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, sublist

I have this code:

```
class A
{ 
public string Prop1;
public string Prop2;
public List<B> Prop3;
}

class B
{ 
public string Value1;
public int Value2;
public double Value3;
}
```

and have List of `A` and I neeed to get `Value1` from `B` if `Value2` from `B` equals to some string. I'd like to use lambda. How can I get it?

Here is the code when I use `foreach`:

```
//I have listA of type List<A>

foreach(var a in listA)
{
   foreach(bar b in a.Prop3
   {
      if(b.Value1=="some string")
      {
          return b.Value2;
      }
   }
}
```

How to use lambda without `foreach`?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use lambda expressions? It's certainly easy enough to do this with LINQ, but you'll gain a lot more from going through a LINQ tutorial than just getting an answer to this one problem, only to have more in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 return listA
    .Select(a => 
        a.Prop3.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Value1 == "some string"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Select create a list containing NULL's and FirstOrDefault will just give you the first, so if the first A does not have a B with matching Value1 you return NULL?

Comment: This is good solution but it returns whole object B. I'll only append ".Value2" at the end and I'll get my result. Thanks!

Comment: @David: Just adding ".Value2" will throw a NullReferenceException when no B exists with "some string".

Comment: Yes, I know. I need only principle how to create this example

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using any

```
    var result=(from c in  listA where
 c.Prop3.Any(c=>c.Value2=="some string") select c.Prop3.Value1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (B b in from a in listA from b in a.Prop3 where b.Value1=="some string" select b)
    {
        return b.Value2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to do something like:

```
return listA.SelectMany(a => a.Prop3).FirstOrDefault(b => b.Value1 == "some string")?.Value2
```

Comment: That returns the correct B, but OPs code returns the value in Value2 of that B.

Comment: Thanks - did mean do do the null propagation thing at the end but forgot

Answer (score 0):

To mirror your code you could use this:

```
return listA
    .SelectMany(x => x.Prop3)
    .Where(x => x.Value1 == "Some string")
    .Select(x => x.Value2)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I would rather try to get the correct `B` and return its `Value2` if one was found:

```
B b = listA
    .SelectMany(x => x.Prop3)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value1 == "Some string");

return b != null
    ? b.Value2
    : string.Empty;
```